# Connection between traces in Cameron-Martin spaces of two Gaussian measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two Gaussian measures defined on a common separable Banach space $B$. Denote their two Cameron-Martin spaces by $H(\mu)$ and $H(\nu)$, respectively.
Let $T: B \to B^{\ast}$ be a continuous linear operator. Then, as $H(\mu) \subseteq B$ and $B^{\ast} \subseteq H(\mu)^{\ast}$ continuously, $T$ can also be regarded as a linear operator on $H(\mu)$ (after identifying it with its dual). Analogously, $T$ can also be regarded as a linear operator on $H(\nu)$.

**My question now is:** Does there exist a continuous linear operator $S$ on $H(\nu)$ such that
\begin{equation*}
  \operatorname{Tr}_{H(\mu)}(T)= \operatorname{Tr}_{H(\nu)}(ST),
\end{equation*}
where $\operatorname{Tr}_H$ denotes the trace in $H$ (and of course assuming that the restrictions of $T$ are trace class)?

I'm hoping for some explicit expression of $S$ in terms of the covariance operators (in the finite-dimensional case, given my calculations are correct, $S$ is just the covariance  matrix of $\mu$).

If the answer is no, do things change if the Cameron-Martin spaces are replaced by the reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces and/or the two Gaussian measures are assumed to be equivalent (so that the Cameron-Martin spaces coincide as sets)?

Any help or reference would be much appreciated!